# Python 2/3 difference in ctypes.cast while trying to copy an array created in C into numpy

Tags: c, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes

I am having a (seemingly) very strange issue. Google seems to be of no help.

In python I call a subroutine written in C. The input is a list of image paths. For each image, the C code detects a list of keypoints -- a location and shape represented by 6 floats.  (It also produces a corresponding list of SIFT descriptors (uint8 / char), but I just want to focus on keypoints). To put the keypoint arrays back into Python I use ctypes to cast outvars of the C function into numpy arrays.

In Python 2.7 the code works, but in Python 3.4 I am having an issue when I am casting the outvars. Specifically when running:

```
 c_arr = ctypes.cast(typed_c_arrptr, arr_t_size)
```

I get:

```
 ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type.
```

---

Which isn't much to go on, so I'll dive into the problem a little deeper

The entry point to the program reads as such:

```
# Relevant type definitions

import ctypes as C
import numpy as np

KPTS_DIM = 6    # number of values per keypoint (x, y, a, b, c, theta)
DESC_DIM = 128  # number of values per descriptor 

kpts_dtype = np.float32
desc_dtype = np.uint8
int_t     = C.c_int
byte_t    = C.c_char
FLAGS_RW = 'aligned, c_contiguous, writeable'
kpts_t       = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=kpts_dtype, ndim=2, flags=FLAGS_RW)
desc_t       = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=desc_dtype, ndim=2, flags=FLAGS_RW)
kpts_array_t = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=kpts_t, ndim=1, flags=FLAGS_RW)
desc_array_t = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=desc_t, ndim=1, flags=FLAGS_RW)
int_array_t  = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=int_t, ndim=1, flags=FLAGS_RW)

def detect_kpts_list(image_paths_list):
    """
    Input: A list of image paths
    Output: A tuple of lists of keypoints and descriptors
    """
    nImgs = len(image_paths_list)  # Get Num Images

    # Cast string list to C 
    if six.PY2:
        realpaths_list = list(map(realpath, image_paths_list))
    if six.PY3:
        # (account for Python3 using unicode)
        realpaths_list = [realpath(path).encode('ascii') for path in image_paths_list]
    # Create c pointer for list of paths
    c_strs = _cast_strlist_to_C(realpaths_list)

    # Allocate empty array pointers for each image
    kpts_ptr_array = np.empty(nImgs, kpts_t)  # array of float arrays
    desc_ptr_array = np.empty(nImgs, desc_t)  # array of byte arrays
    # Allocate integer array storing the number of keypoints per image
    nDetect_array = np.empty(nImgs, int_t)  # array of detections per image

    # Detect keypoints
    clib.detectKeypointsList(nImgs, c_strs,
                             kpts_ptr_array, desc_ptr_array,
                             nDetect_array, ...
```

The relevant C code looks like this:

```
// Accepts a list of image_paths, and produces a keypoint list for each input
void detectKeypointsList(int num_filenames,
        char** image_filename_list,
        float** keypoints_array,   // <- the outvar in question (the first layer of pointers has been pre-allocated)
        uint8** descriptors_array,
        int* length_array,
{

    ...

    for(index=0;index < num_filenames;++index)
    {
        // Run detect keypoints for each image
        detectKeypoints(image_filename_list[index],
                &(keypoints_array[index]), &(descriptors_array[index]),
                &(length_array[index]),
                ...
    }
}

   // Function which runs for each image.
void detectKeypoints(char* image_filename, float** keypoints, uint8** descriptors, int* length, ...
{
    Detector* detector = make_new_detector();
    // Get num keypoints detected
    *length = detector->detect();
    // Allocate space for this image's keypoints and descriptors
    *keypoints = new float[(*length)*KPTS_DIM]; // <- Where allocation for a single image
    *descriptors = new uint8[(*length)*DESC_DIM];
    // Populate the allocated outvars
    detector->exportArrays((*length), *keypoints, *descriptors);
    //may need to add support for "use_adaptive_scale" and "nogravity_hack" here (needs translation from Python to C++ first)
    delete detector;
}
```

So, to the best of my knowledge, everything should be ok at this point, because Python allocated a pointer for each image, and then C used that pointer to allocate a float array depending on the number of keypoints in the image. Furthermore it works in Python 2.7, so I'm fairly confident in that code.

Now, this is where the more difficult stuff begins. We have to get all of those arrays back into python. The next two lines call a helper function.

```
# Cast keypoint array to list of numpy keypoints
kpts_list = extract_2darr_list(nDetect_array, kpts_ptr_array, kpts_t, kpts_dtype, KPTS_DIM)
# Cast descriptor array to list of numpy descriptors
desc_list = extract_2darr_list(nDetect_array, desc_ptr_array, desc_t, desc_dtype, DESC_DIM)
```

The helper definition is:

```
def extract_2darr_list(size_list, ptr_list, arr_t, arr_dtype,
                        arr_dim):
    """
    size_list - contains the size of each output 2d array
    ptr_list  - an array of pointers to the head of each output 2d
                array (which was allocated in C)
    arr_t     - the C pointer type
    arr_dtype - the numpy array type
    arr_dim   - the number of columns in each output 2d array
    """
    arr_list = [arrptr_to_np(arr_ptr, (size, arr_dim), arr_t, arr_dtype)
                    for (arr_ptr, size) in zip(ptr_list, size_list)]
    return arr_list
```

which calls another helper.

```
def arrptr_to_np(c_arrptr, shape, arr_t, dtype):
    """
    Casts an array pointer from C to numpy
    Input:
        c_arrpt - an array pointer returned from C
        shape   - shape of that array pointer
        arr_t   - the ctypes datatype of c_arrptr
    """
    itemsize_ = dtype().itemsize
    ptr_t = byte_t * itemsize_
    arr_t_size = C.POINTER(ptr_t)                      # size of each item
    typed_c_arr_ptr = c_arrptr.astype(int)             # not sure why this is int
    c_arr = C.cast(typed_c_arr_ptr, arr_t_size)        # cast to ctypes
    np_arr = np.ctypeslib.as_array(c_arr, shape)       # cast to numpy
    np_arr.dtype = dtype                               # fix numpy dtype
    return np_arr
```

I apparently don't have a strong grasp on this function, I was not the original author. When I saw the error my first response was to attack this line:

```
        typed_c_arr_ptr = c_arrptr.astype(int)
```

I guessed it had something to do with int being an int32 in Python 2.7 and a int64 in Python 3.4. I tried changing it to np.int32, ctypes.c_int32, ... on and on, the only value which made the program work was if I changed it to ctypes.c_char, but when I did that the float arrays contained incorrect values.

I think that is a reasonably complete summary of my program, unfortunately I can't think of an easy way to decouple the code to let other people test it (unless someone wants to try and pull the repo: https://github.com/Erotemic/hesaff, and it loosely depends on this pure python repo as well: https://github.com/Erotemic/utool, I am currently working on the branch PyQt5)

---

I went so far as to print out the type and value of local variables running from Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, they were both the same in all relevant places.

This is the output in Python 2.7 when I manually threw an error where it was happening in Python 3.4:

```
[!arrptr_to_np] byte_t = <class 'ctypes.c_char'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(byte_t) = <type '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] arr_t = <class 'numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer_<f4_2d_ALIGNED_C_CONTIGUOUS_WRITEABLE'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(arr_t) = <type '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] arr_t_size = <class 'pyhesaff._pyhesaff.LP_c_char_Array_4'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(arr_t_size) = <type '_ctypes.PyCPointerType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] c_arr = <pyhesaff._pyhesaff.LP_c_char_Array_4 object at 0x06075D50>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(c_arr) = <class 'pyhesaff._pyhesaff.LP_c_char_Array_4'>

[!arrptr_to_np] c_arrptr = 84395128
[!arrptr_to_np] type(c_arrptr) = <type 'numpy.uint32'>

[!arrptr_to_np] dtype = <type 'numpy.float32'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(dtype) = <type 'type'>

[!arrptr_to_np] itemsize_ = 4
[!arrptr_to_np] type(itemsize_) = <type 'int'>

[!arrptr_to_np] ptr_t = <class 'pyhesaff._pyhesaff.c_char_Array_4'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(ptr_t) = <type '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] shape = (640, 6)
[!arrptr_to_np] type(shape) = <type 'tuple'>

[!arrptr_to_np] typed_c_arrptr = 84395128
[!arrptr_to_np] type(typed_c_arrptr) = <type 'numpy.int32'>
```

This is the output in Python 3.4, which threw an error all by itself.

```
[!arrptr_to_np] byte_t = <class 'ctypes.c_char'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(byte_t) = <class '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] arr_t = <class 'numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer_<f4_2d_ALIGNED_C_CONTIGUOUS_WRITEABLE'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(arr_t) = <class '_ctypes.PyCSimpleType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] arr_t_size = <class 'pyhesaff._pyhesaff.LP_c_char_Array_4'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(arr_t_size) = <class '_ctypes.PyCPointerType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] c_arrptr = 46460400
[!arrptr_to_np] type(c_arrptr) = <class 'numpy.uint64'>

[!arrptr_to_np] dtype = <class 'numpy.float32'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(dtype) = <class 'type'>

[!arrptr_to_np] itemsize_ = 4
[!arrptr_to_np] type(itemsize_) = <class 'int'>

[!arrptr_to_np] ptr_t = <class 'pyhesaff._pyhesaff.c_char_Array_4'>
[!arrptr_to_np] type(ptr_t) = <class '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'>

[!arrptr_to_np] shape = (640, 6)
[!arrptr_to_np] type(shape) = <class 'tuple'>

[!arrptr_to_np] typed_c_arrptr = 46460400
[!arrptr_to_np] type(typed_c_arrptr) = <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I seem to have exhausted all my options. Can anybody see something that I might have overlooked?